# How to add a simple custom controller with last version of backpack

Tags: laravel-backpack

I previously use this code to add a custom ( not crud ) controller:view handled by backpack.

By handled I mean just let backpack do the templating and authentification job call my controller and serve my view in the subtemplate.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth'], 'prefix' => config('backpack.base.route_prefix', 'admin')], function () {
  Route::get("/stats", 'MyStateController@index');
  Route::get("/infos", 'MyInfosController@index');
});
```

It doesn't seems to work anymore as I get this error :

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException Route
>   [login] not defined.

Same error if I remove the 'auth' middleware.
I dont find any documentation to this simple need. What should I do ?

Comment: by "previously" you mean version 3.*?

Comment: I think `auth` middleware is now `admin` by looking at code in this file https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/blob/4.0.9/src/routes/backpack/custom.php

Comment: Yes, version 3.* . Add the 'admin' middleware solves the issue, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Working code :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'admin'], 'prefix' => config('backpack.base.route_prefix', 'admin')], function () {
  Route::get("/stats", 'MyStateController@index');
  Route::get("/infos", 'MyInfosController@index');
});
```